# Issue with mvc, partial view dispaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question about partial view. I want to display in header Login form which i created. In HomeController I have 2 actions: one is Login and other is Login with httppost method. 
In partial view (_Layout.cshtml) I have a code - only send footer div:

```
 <td style="text-align:center">
        <h3>Bookstore</h3>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") 
 </td>
```

In Login view I have:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
        <td>@Html.PasswordFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(Users u)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        using (DatabaseLoginEntities dl = new DatabaseLoginEntities()) {
            var v = dl.Users.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(u.Username) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != null) {
                Session["LogedUserId"] = v.UserAccountID.ToString();
                Session["LogedUserFullName"] = v.FullName.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
            }
        }
    }
    return PartialView("_LoginPartial", u);
}
```

When press Login button, mvc switches me to separate page in which Login form is shown. I don't want that to happen. It must stay in header. Functionality is ok but I have issue how to show that only in header. Has anyone have idea where I'm wrong?

Comment: Show your controller code for Login actions

Answer (score 0):

you must use ajax

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Home",
                                      new AjaxOptions
                                      {
                                          HttpMethod = "Post",
                                          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                                          ,
                                          UpdateTargetId = "div_id"
                                      }
                                    )){
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Username)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
        <td>@Html.PasswordFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Password)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Comment: Also, ensure that your action AfterLogin returns a partial view, or the  entire page will be rendered in the target element.